# Passing arguments to fixture in TestCase with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

How to pass custom arguments to fixture inside test method of `unittest.TestCase` derived class using **pytest**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for definitely too long time I managed to invent solution with usage of [doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html) and threads about wrapping fixtures. I hope somebody will find it useful.

***conftest.py***

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def add(request):
    def wrapped(a=10, b=5):
        return a + b
    request.cls.add = wrapped
```

***add_test.py***

```
import pytest
from unittest import TestCase

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('add')
class AddTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        # parameters can be passed inside test method
        result = self.add(2, 2) 
        assert result == 4
```